# Relationship among three European call options

Tags: options

Consider three European call options with strikes $K_1<K_2<K_3$ all at the same expiration time T.
If we assume the absence of arbitrage at all earlier times t, there is a derived equation from the properties of option
$$C(K_2)<\frac{K_3-K_2}{K_3-K_1}C(K_1)+\frac{K_2-K_1}{K_3-K_1}C(K_3)$$
Could someone explain how to think about this equation?

Comment: The relation above is not true. Could you please check?

Comment: What do you want to know? This relation doesn't hold. It'll be different if the right hand is a sum instead of an inequality. Check for that.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. The right hand should be a sum. Could you explain how to show this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C(K)$ is a convex function of strike, therefore it holds that:

$$C\left( t K_1 + (1-t) K_2 \right) \leq t C\left( K_1 \right) + (1-t) C\left( K_2 \right)
$$
with $t = \frac{K_3-K_2}{K_3-K_1}$.